# How to store ISO time into mongodb with timestamp being 0000000 using C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, timestamp

I want to store a DateTime instance into MongoDB using  C#. As mongodb uses ISO 8601 as format, the date which I am passing is getting stored with a timestamp which is making querying using that date field a nightmare. I tried DateTime.Now, DateTime.UtcNow, BsonDateTime object but all are saving with current timestamp only. Is there a way using which I can make my date field to store date and rest as Zeros,
Thanks

Piyush Kumar

Comment: you mean ignore time and offset ? 
What is wrong with DateTime.UtcNow ?

Comment: DateTime.UtcNow is inserting with timestamp, which make equality check impossible. I am able to query using greater than condition and passing the time with offsets as zero. While going gor equality checks it fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a class map for your class to only store the date part of the datetime with the following code:

```cs
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Order>(map =>
{
    map.MapProperty(x => x.Date)
        .SetSerializer(DateTimeSerializer.DateOnlyInstance);
});
```

then when execute the following

```cs
var client = new MongoClient();
var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = database.GetCollection<Order>("orders");

await collection.InsertOneAsync(new Order
{
    Name = "MyOrder", Date = DateTime.UtcNow.Date
});
```

we'll get the following in the database

```js
> db.orders.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ed8fb7050eb018e5ee13e73"),
        "Date" : ISODate("2020-06-04T00:00:00Z")
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot,worked like knife through butter.... I was stuck on this for so many days :)